# Unable to connect remotely to MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, database, linux, ubuntu, remote-access

I'm currently trying to setup a remote connection to a mysql database. I've done this before, and wrote down some steps to follow for next time, but I can't seem to get this one working. Here's the process I've taken so far.

For the purposes of this question, we'll say that my DB is at ip 100.100.100.100 and the remote host I'm trying to connect from is 100.100.100.200.

Ubuntu Server using Mac OSX terminal:

**MySQL is installed, and I've logged in as the root**

**I've edited my /etc/mysql/my.cnf file to look like this**

bind-address = 100.100.100.100
there is no --skip-networking field in my file

**Restart mysql**

**create a new user and grant privileges**
CREATE USER 'user1'@100.100.100.200
GRANT ALL ON *.* to 'user1'

**then I update the iptables**
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --destination-port 3306 -j ACCEPT

**after all this is finished, I log out of mysql, and try to connect from the remote server with the new user**

**while on ip 100.100.100.200**
mysql -h100.100.100.100 -uuser1

**and I get this error message**
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '100.100.100.100' (110)

is there something I've missed in the process, or could it be something with the servers firewall? I've been scouring the internet for hours trying to figure this out, so the next step was to ask a question. Thanks in advance for any help you can give!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Man that was a pain.

The problem was in the iptables. I simply restarted the server and re-ran the iptable command. 
Restarting the server clears all the iptable rules unless they have been explicitly saved.
Here's the resource I used to find out more about iptables.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-using-ip-tables-on-ubuntu-12-04

**sudo reboot** - restart the server

**/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --destination-port 3306 -j ACCEPT** - add rule to iptables

Not sure what was going wrong, but after a restart and a reinsert of the rule, everything worked like a charm.